# What is the python command for matlab invoke?

Tags: python, invoke

I have a Matlab Example which connects to COM-object and calls a method:

```
S = invoke(c,methodName,arg1,...,argN)
```

I am trying to translate the Matlab code to python. I successfully connected the COM-Object (pywin32), but i didn't found a translation for the Matlab code showing above.

Can somebody help?

Thx,
hulu